# Passing arrays from laravel controller to view

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Please l am working with array in laravel. I want a way to access some values and display them as forms fields in blade.php file.

This is the array :

```
$postData = array(
            'source_addr' => 'JJA ENT',

    'encoding' => 0,
            'schedule_time' => '',
            'message' => 'Hello World',
            'recipients' => 

   [array('recipient_id' =>       '1', 'dest_addr' => '233554463045'),   array('recipient_id' => '2', 'dest_addr' => '255700000011')]
        );
```

This is how I return the view in this controller :

```
    return     view('main',compact('postData'));
```

In the blade file

```
<body>
    {{$postData['message']}}
```

This output the value corresponding to the message in the array.

I now want a way to get the attributes of the "recipients" too but when I pass the recipients like the way I did to the message, it returned errors.

This is how I return the view in the controller

```
   return view('main',compact('postData'));
```

In the blade

```
<body>
    {{$postData['message']}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `foreach` Loop to get array values in blade. Here is an example

```
{{$postData['message']}}

@foreach ($postData['recipients'] as $recipient)
    <input type="text" name="recipient_id[]" value="{{$recipient['recipient_id']}}">
    <input type="text" name="dest_addr[]" value="{{$recipient['dest_addr']}}">
@endforeach
```

Comment: thanks so much for your response. It did answer my question very well. The only thing left is that, I want to now enter the recipient_id and dest_addr and remove those values from the array in the controller so that the function should still work the same. this is the full function in the controller:

Comment: this is the function in controller

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't mix different array notations. You'll only confuse yourself for no reason. `array()` was used to keep compatibility with very old PHP versions that are no longer maintained. You should use `[ ]` instead.

```php
$postData = [
    'source_addr' => 'JJA ENT',
    'encoding' => 0,
    'schedule_time' => '',
    'message' => 'Hello World',
    'recipients' => [
        [
            'recipient_id' => '1',
            'dest_addr' => '233554463045'
        ],
        [
            'recipient_id' => '2',
            'dest_addr' => '255700000011'
        ]
    ]
];

return view('main', [
    'postData' => $postData
]);
```

```xml
<p>Source Address: {{ $postData['source_addr'] }}</p>
<p>Encoding: {{ $postData['encoding'] }}</p>
<p>Schedule Time: {{ $postData['schedule_time'] }}</p>
<p>Message: {{ $postData['message'] }}</p>
<p>Recipients</p>
<ul>
  @foreach ($postData['recipients'] as $recipient)
    <li>ID: {{ $recipient['recipient_id'] }}. Address: {{ $recipient['dest_addr'] }}</li>
  @endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: Great response. Thanks so much. Please how I do I change the blade file content here into input? I want to have this same as input fields that will accept the inputs so that i will enter the values of the array here instead of in the controller. For example, if I enter  {{ $postData['message'] }}, and remove the value from the array in the controller, it should still work.